# How does this 'else' work?

Tags: c++

I'm getting a warning that suggests to put explicit braces to avoid ambiguous 'else'.

What's the equivalent to this code if I put brackets? Or is this actually reading as 'else if'?

```
    void balance(Node * & x)
    {
        if (x == nullptr)
            return;
        if (height(x->left) - height(x->right) > 1)
            if(height(x->left->left) >= height(x->left->right))
                rotateLeft(x);
            else
                doubleRotateLeft(x);
        else                                                      // this one
        if (height(x->right) - height(x->left) > 1)
            if(height(x->right->right) >= height(x->right->left))
                rotateRight(x);
            else
                doubleRotateRight(x);

        x->height = max(height(x->left), height(x->right)) + 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed "reading as 'else if'", however if you were to use the brackets you (in the future) or any other reader of your code would not have a need to even raise a question of what code block does that `else` belong to ;-)

This usage of brackets will yield even better results if some time later you were to add more lines of code before the `return;` block. With no brackets you are running into a possibility of making an "innocent" mistake of completely changing the logic of your code.

Answer (score 2):

For the love of kittens, **use** brackets -- espicially for this mess.  Yes it is `else if` right now.

Answer (score 1):

It's reading as `else if`. The equivalent code utilizing braces and proper formatting:

```
void balance(Node * & x)
{
    if (x == nullptr) {
        return;
    }
    if (height(x->left) - height(x->right) > 1) {
        if(height(x->left->left) >= height(x->left->right)) {
            rotateLeft(x);
        }
        else {
            doubleRotateLeft(x);
        }
    }
    else if (height(x->right) - height(x->left) > 1) {
        if(height(x->right->right) >= height(x->right->left)) {
            rotateRight(x);
        }
        else {
            doubleRotateRight(x);
        }
    }
    x->height = max(height(x->left), height(x->right)) + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void balance(Node * & x)
{
    if (x == nullptr)
    {
        return;
    }
    if (height(x->left) - height(x->right) > 1)
    {
        if(height(x->left->left) >= height(x->left->right))
        {
            rotateLeft(x);
        }
        else
        {
            doubleRotateLeft(x);
        }
    }
    else if (height(x->right) - height(x->left) > 1) // this one
    {
        if(height(x->right->right) >= height(x->right->left))
        {
            rotateRight(x);
        }
        else
        {
            doubleRotateRight(x);
        }
    }

    x->height = max(height(x->left), height(x->right)) + 1;
}
```

This is the code that compiler think you are writing. Because "else if" consider unlimited amount of space in between, so all the books suggest to put brackets all the time.

I think in your case, the auto bracket and the logic I guess from your indentation seems provide the same result.